# Lock file for application

Tags: c#, file, locking

I working on a service. This service will run on 2 gears using a shared folder.

Shared folder contains images, the service read an image, do some stuff and move the file. I want that the both running services can't access to the same file and prevent user from deleting processing file.

Actually I have this :

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("My Folder");
List<FileInfo> fileList = info.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo file in fileList)
{
    bool createdNew;
    Mutex fileLocker = new Mutex(true, file.Name, out createdNew);
    if (createdNew)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.FullName));
       // Do some stuff
       if (null != fileLocker) fileLocker.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

It prevent 2 access the file on the same machine but not in separate, and user can delete file while the service is using it.

How can I lock the file properly ?

Comment: Read the file in a locking way, that way the filesystem lock would achieve what you try to do in your code, check [V0ldek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51783717/2265446) on locking the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your file using a `FileStream` and specify the `FileShare` parameter:

```
var file = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

EDIT:

To use `BitmapImage` with a `FileStream` you need to use the `BitmapImage.StreamSource` property. So something like this:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

var file = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.StreamSource = file;
bitmapImage.EndInit();
```

After this you need to decide how you're gonna handle the `Stream`'s disposal. You can either force the bitmap to cache it and then clean it up immediately, or 
let the bitmap retain stream access. More on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm actually opening the file with `BitmapImage` from file path(i'm getting the file with `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`). Should I load my image with `FileStream` instead of `Uri` or just load FileStream like the Mutex ?

Comment: I added an edit to help you out with `BitmapImage` initialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what I was looking for